# Xcode - account already has valid iOS Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

My developer team has recently added a new distribution certificate to our Apple Developer account. I downloaded it, and it is now on my Keychain. However, I get this message in Xcode:

> You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate and request a new one.

When I go to Preferences > Accounts > View Details, I only see 1 certificate signing identity "iOS Development". How do I add the new Distribution certificate? I thought it was enough to just install it on my Keychain. When I try to drag the certificate from my Keychain to the signing identities in the View Details section, it doesn't work because I can't drag it in there.

I thought downloading the distribution certificate was enough to have it "installed locally" as Xcode said, but apparently it's not effective.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "I downloaded it, and it is now on my Keychain" That should be all you need, because Xcode can see into your keychain (unless you have denied it permission). Did you tell the accounts Details to Refresh?

Comment: Yes, and I still only see the "iOS Development" certificate showing up. How can I check if I denied it permission or not to see into my keychain?

Comment: When I click refresh I get a window saying, "Certificates Not Found: The following certificates were not found on the Member Center. Xcode can submit certificate signing requests on your behalf. Please select the certificates that you want Xcode to request." Aside from the Mac certificates (which I don't need) it lists these that I can check boxes of: The Developer ID Application Certificate, and The Developer ID Installer Certificate. Are these the ones I want? I'm hesitant to request these because I don't want to screw anything up :(

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351864/855261

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode / Preferences / Accounts - your apple id, is a member of the developer team? To the bottom right (of Accounts tab), under team name, it may default to "(your name) (Personal Team)", but there should also be another choice "(your team's name)". So if your team is named "The Awesome Team", then "The Awesome Team" should be selected under "Team Name", not your personal name.

**UPDATE:**
How to "*select the team name*" has varied from version to version of Xcode.
First step is to **click on the team name**.
Then click on a button below it. In one version, that button said "Show Details..".  As I write this, the button says "Download all profiles".

Another alternative is to **double-click** the team name. This should pop up some dialog.

To verify that the desired team is still selected, you will have to quit Xcode, open it again, go to Preferences / Accounts again.

**UPDATE #2:**
In newer versions of Xcode, it seems that the real problem is "Automatically Manage Signing" isn't making the desired choice. Find that, and turn it off, then select the desired certificate. [Sagar Mody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071522/199364) explains a bit more.

---

If still not working for you, but works for someone else, might be worth asking them for screenshots of what they see in (1) Member Center in browser - Certificates, Provisioning Profiles, (2) Xcode / Preferences / Account, (3) "View Details" for their account. Worst case, ask them to temporarily change their password, and try THEIR account on your computer, verify you can get everything working if you log in as them. If you can do that, then there is something not set up right for your account. Try to find a difference in Member Center, or in those Xcode screenshots.

Comment: I already solved this long ago, but your answer is technically right. Hopefully will be helpful to others with the same predicament.

Comment: This "answer" only describes the problem, doesnt' provide a solution. So  your first paragraph describe my situation, how do I fix it? How do I get my team name to be selected instead of my name? Down voting.

Comment: @Fernando - to select the team name, click on it, then click the link that says "Download All Profiles" (In earlier version, click on "View Details.." link). Depending on Xcode version / updates, might instead need to **double-click** the team name. For me, whichever one I've accessed last, stays active next time.  [Editing this update into the answer also.]

Comment: @Fernando - I've added "Update" and "Update #2" to my answer - do either of those "provide a solution"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by @toolmakersteve is technically right.

To achieve that what I did was, disabled "Automatically Manage Signing" then in Signing (Debug) / (Release) select "Eligible" bundle identifier.

From https://develop.apple.com/accounts download the Distribution Profile of XC: (Eligible bundle identifier). Double click on it install into Keychain Access.

Ensure in Xcode under "Signing Certificate" it shows "iPhone Distribution: (Organisation Name)" and not "iPhone Developer: (Your / Developer Name"

Now build and archive and the export worked successfully for me. Hope this solves the issue for you too. This was really frustrating.

Comment: NOTE: If someone has trouble getting this to work, may also need to delete an OLD certificate + key in Keychain Access.  That is, if still not working, remove the one for the account or signature you don't want to use currently. (I wouldn't do this at first) ALSO make sure there is no OBSOLETE/expired entry for the account you are trying to use!  Make sure Xcode only sees the one you want it to use. (Shouldn't be necessary if you've turned off "Automatically Manage Signing", and selected the desired team/organization, but I mention it as one more step to try, if necessary.)

Comment: AFAIK, The "download" step in this answer is only necessary if the desired option isn't showing up under "Signing Certificate".  So, first try to disable Automatic signing, and see if the desired option is available to select. If it isn't, then **Account / Preferences / double-click the team/organization name** and/or click it and then the button **"download all profiles"**. If still don't see correct certificate as a choice, then you'll have to manually do the download Sagar describes.

Comment: Where do you find "Automatically Manage Signing", in order to disable it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade - [Here is link to an Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html) that mentions "Automatically Manage Signing".

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time looking for what was wrong and my concern was quite different.

**Everything was well configured**, all the certificates were present locally and the provisioning profiles.

Yet Xcode Organizer kept saying that my new distribution certificate was not present in my Keychain.

Basically, this famous distribution certificate was not trusted on my local machine. I had to trust it by following this procedure: [https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/change-the-trust-settings-of-a-certificate-kyca11871/mac#:~:text=In%20the%20Keychain%20Access%20app,from%20the%20pop%2Dup%20menus](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/change-the-trust-settings-of-a-certificate-kyca11871/mac#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Keychain%20Access%20app,from%20the%20pop%2Dup%20menus).