# You already have a current iOS Development certificate or a pending certificate request

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

[image: Issue in below the picture]

I installed new OSX High Siera,
  issue: All installed certificates deleted.
  so i created New distribution certificate with my local machine signingCertificate, and downloaded and installed into machine. 
When i run project or it giving error. i tried all steps found in stackOverflow, but could not resolve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have an enterprise developer account then you only allow creating 3 prod certificates. If none of your .p12 is in your system then you may ask the owner for .p12 or generate new certificate by revoking any from three.

**At a time only 3 release/production certificate for a developer account <strike>(non-enterprise)</strike>.**

Comment: 3 release certificates tip saved my day.

Comment: yes i was not aware about it. I checked your answer and deleted 1 certificate from developer portal and that's it. it worked.. thanks man

Comment: I have an Enterprise account and there still seems to be a three certificate limit.

Comment: Oh, so I think I should update my answer. Thanks (:

Comment: This saved my day, delete extra development certificates and it will work

Answer (score 4):

1. Fetch all provision profiles through `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Download Manual Profiles`
2. I suggest to use `Manual signing` instead of Automatic.
3. Choose Provision profile for manual signing, the one you should create using distribution certificate.

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Revoke that certificate which you are going to use and create it again manually or automatically from xCode. It helped me at last.

Answer (score 0):

When I am creating a new certificate from my Xcode 9.2 the error was appears `"You already have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request"`.

Just 2 steps to fix this error.

1. Remove old certificate from developer.apple.com
2. Create a new certificate from Xcode or developer.apple.com

My problem has been solved (I am using Xcode 9.2).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Keychain Access.app
2. Select "Login" and Search `Apple Development:{your apple ID}`
3. Backup all search result(if needed)
4. Delete this one(or more) Certificate
5. Restart Xcode, it will automatic repair this problem.

This work for me.